# DT:datatableAjax stuck at "Processing..." Server=False works fine

Tags: r, shiny, datatables

I cannot figure out what my issue is. The code bellow does not work and the datatable is stuck displaying `Processing...` with the browser console warning:

> "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400
>   (Bad Request)"

On the server:

```
     output$dt <- DT::renderDataTable({
        dtdf <- data1()[,-13:-14] %>%
          mutate(Action = paste('<a class="go-map" href="" data-lat="', Latitude, '" data-long="', Longitude, '" data-zip="', ID, '"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pushpin"></i></a>', sep=""))
        action <- DT::dataTableAjax(session, dtdf)
        DT::datatable(dtdf, extensions = 'Buttons', options = list(ajax = list(url = action), dom = 'Bfrtip', buttons = c('excel', 'pdf'), pageLength = 25, columnDefs = list(list(className = 'dt-center', targets ="_all"))), escape = FALSE)
      })
```

On the ui:

```
 DT::dataTableOutput("dt")
```

Simply changing to the option `server=FALSE`, like below, works as expected. However, my dataset is too large to disable server-side processing.

```
  output$dt <- DT::renderDataTable({
    dtdf <- data1()[,-13:-14] %>%
      mutate(Action = paste('<a class="go-map" href="" data-lat="', Latitude, '" data-long="', Longitude, '" data-zip="', ID, '"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pushpin"></i></a>', sep=""))
    action <- DT::dataTableAjax(session, dtdf)
    DT::datatable(dtdf, extensions = 'Buttons', options = list(ajax = list(url = action), dom = 'Bfrtip', buttons = c('excel', 'pdf'), pageLength = 25, columnDefs = list(list(className = 'dt-center', targets ="_all"))), escape = FALSE)
  }, server = FALSE)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone having similar issues, try installing the latest version!

A fresh install of DT with `devtools::install_github('rstudio/DT')` seems to have solved it for me!